# How correctly create Spring Boot controllers for URL that contains nested objects?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, spring-boot, restful-url

I develop Spring Boot application that have such domain objects.

Task object:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Task {
    private String title;
    private TaskCategory category;
}
```

DayPlan object:

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class DayPlan {
    LocalDate date;
    List<Task> tasks = new LinkedList<>();
}
```

The general URL to work with objects is:

`/plans/{date}/tasks/{taskId}`

I need to process such URLs:

1. `/plans/2017-07-30` or `/plans/2017-07-30/tasks` - to view all tasks
   for selected date;
2. `/plans/2017-07-30/tasks/1` - to view task #1 for
   date 2017-07-30;
3. `/plans/2017-07-30/tasks/2/add-after` - to add new task after task #2;
4. `/plans/2017-07-30/tasks/2/add-before` - to add new task before task #2;

So my question is - how correctly create controllers according to 'single responsibility principle'? Should I create one general PlanController with two @PathVariable's?

Or should I create two different controllers for DayPlan and Task objects? How to process request mapping for tasks in this case?

What is best practices for such situations? Thanks.